# Oracle SQL Date difference from end of month

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select pdat
      ,ac_no
      , bal
 from dummy_table;

PDATE     | AC_NO | BAL  
========================    
14/02/2012| abcd  | 1200    
15/02/2012| abcd  | 1300
27/02/2012| abcd  | 1300
```

My question is how can I make the `result set to fetch`

```
PDATE     | AC_NO | BAL  | Difference
=====================================
14/02/2012| abcd  | 1200 |    8
22/02/2012| abcd  | 1300 |    7
```

Difference of row one is calculated on the basis of `22/02/2012-14/02/2012`.
     But how can I calculate the difference of last date from the month's ending date? in   this case `29th Feb 2012`

Comment: Why 22/02/2012 for the first row?  What should happen to the rows with 15/02/2012 and 27/02/2012?

Comment: What about to substrat to [last_day()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions072.htm)?

Comment: @nightWatcher:How you get 22/02/2012 ? where there is a record 15/02/2012

Comment: you should post your current query... How is calcuated pdate 22/02/2012 from the initial set?

Comment: Dates are already present in table, i only have to calculate difference from next date

Comment: @nightWatcher, 22/02/2012 is not in the upper table, but both 15/02/2012 and 27/02/2012 are.  How does the query for the lower table look like at the moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key here is `LEAD function` - read documentation about `analytical functions in SQL`, they are very powerful tool. `LEAD(pdat) OVER (ORDER BY pdat)` gets you value of pdat in `next row` which comes in `ascending order of pdat`. Then `nvl function` takes care about `last date` where there is `no next date` - it uses `last_day(pdat)` function call which returns last day of a month pdat falls in.

If you want to handle several months - you will need to do some analysis with `DECODE function` to detect if pdat and `LEAD(pdat) OVER (ORDER BY pdat)` belong to the same month, and to use either `LEAD(pdat) OVER (ORDER BY pdat)` or last_day(pdat) as date you are comparing against. I will leave it as your homework.

```
 create table dummy_table(pdat date, ac_no varchar2(10), bal number);

 insert into dummy_table values ('14-FEB-2012', 'abcd', 1200);
 insert into dummy_table values ('15-FEB-2012', 'abcd', 1300);
 insert into dummy_table values ('27-FEB-2012', 'abcd', 1300);

 select pdat
     , ac_no
     , bal
     , nvl(lead(pdat) over (order by pdat) - pdat, last_day(pdat) - pdat) 
  from dummy_table;

 2/14/2012 abcd 1200  1
 2/15/2012 abcd 1300 12
 2/27/2012 abcd 1300  2
```